# Adventureworks restore failed

Tags: sql-server

I've just installed MS SQL Server Express 2014 and SQL Server Management Studio 2014 under Windows 10. I'm following the official Microsoft tutorial on database fundamentals, which uses the Adventureworks DW2008 database. I have tried to restore this dB using the Restore GUI, but it fails every time, as shown here:

[AdventureWorks restore failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU72O.jpg)

I have verified the backup media, but it still fails. I have also restored a different dB, and that worked fine, so I know I am following the correct procedure. I have the file (AdventureworksDW2008Big.bak) in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup
```

Yes, I have thoroughly researched this, but still apologies if there is already an answer on here - I couldn't find it.

Comment: What edition of win10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **DW** in the filename is for Data Warehouse and only works on that edition of SQL Server. As you only installed SQL Express you cannot use it.

Why not try [Adventure Works 2014 Full Database Backup.zip](https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550) instead. If you really need 2008/R2 try the none-DW from [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587):

- AdventureWorks2008R2_Database.zip
- AdventureWorks2008_Database.zip

Comment: Apologies to all - I actually found the correct file while DaveShaw was typing his excellent suggestion, for which many thanks. I restored it, and it worked perfectly. I LOVE stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it will solve your problem or not,
but I had same problem. I mean I am using SQL SERVER 2017 and I wanted to restore AdventureWorks2012.
I received restore failed error, and I decided to restore AdventureWorks2017. my queries on AdventureWorks2012 in an older system in university led to the same results as my queries in AdventureWorks2017 in my system. if you are using a version of SQL SERVER and trying to restore an older or another version of AdventureWorks, you can try the same way.
I mean restoring a version of AdventureWorks which is the same as the version of your SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

1. Best to run SSMS as an administrator to avoid access denied errors (do this by right click on SSMS and choose More -> administrator)
2. copy adventureworksxx.bak into the sql server DATA directory where by
   default all databases are usually located. ( Note: if it is in other directory
   the restore may not find it OR may cause errors later)
3. Restore the database